# can not run native module official example

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module

I followed the document and try to invoke ToastExample.show() from react native.
But it always show
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBV4p.png)

My code:

public class CustomToastPackage implements ReactPackage {

```
@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
        ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    modules.add(new ToastModule(reactContext));

    return modules;
}
```

}

```
public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";

public ToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
}
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "ToastExample";
}
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put(DURATION_SHORT_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    constants.put(DURATION_LONG_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return constants;
}
@ReactMethod
public void show(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
}
```

}

MainApplication.Java:

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new ReanimatedPackage(),
                new VectorIconsPackage(),
                new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
                new CustomToastPackage(),
                new RNSharedPreferencesReactPackage()

        );
    }
```

ToastExample.js:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
module.exports = NativeModules.ToastExample;
```

In my screen:

```
import ToastExample from './ToastExample'
ToastExample.show('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT);
```

I have tried run-android and ./gradlew clean many times.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: NativeModules.ToastExample.show('Awesome', ToastExample.SHORT); same?